# python turtle returning varibles from coords

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is there a way to recall preset lines of code depending on the turtle's position?

I've tried using `turtle.pos()` and `xcor/ycor` but I can't get it to recall the code.

I have tried:

    `if turtle.pos == (0.00,50.00):
        combat()`

I am new to Python turtle.

```
import turtle

GRID_UNIT = 50
GRID_SIZE = 5  # code below assumes this is an odd number

####################################################################
def Combat():
print('You encounter a raverous Spider! do you wish to fight it?')
Fight = str(input())
if Fight == 'Yes':
    #########Battle Code Warrior############
    import random
    import time


    While_Loop = 1
    ###########Battle 1############
    print('============================================')
    while While_Loop == 1:
            if Foe >= 0:
                time.sleep(1)
                print('You did', Player_Dmg,'Dmg')
                Foe = Foe - Player_Dmg # checks health remaining
                print('Your Foe has ',Foe,'Hp left')
                print('=============================')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                Player_Dmg = random.randrange(0,10)
                if Foe <= 0:
                    print('You killed it')
                    break

                else:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    if life >= 0:
                        life = life - Foe_Dmg
                        print('You took ', Foe_Dmg,'Dmg')
                        print('You Have', life, 'Hp left')
                        print('=============================')
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        Foe_Dmg = random.randrange(0, 10)
                        if life <= 0:
                            print('You are dead')

            else:
                print('You die')
                life = 0
                break

elif Fight == 'No':
    print('You Sprint Frantically away from the spider while it chases  you down!')    
def Map_Starting_Area():

turtle.pu()
turtle.goto(-GRID_SIZE/2 * GRID_UNIT, -GRID_SIZE/2 * GRID_UNIT)
turtle.ht()
turtle.pd()

####### Grid ###########

for _ in range(GRID_SIZE // 2):
    turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.right(90)

turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(GRID_UNIT)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
turtle.left(90)

for _ in range(GRID_SIZE // 2):
    turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.right(90)

turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(GRID_UNIT)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
turtle.pu()
turtle.left(90)
turtle.fd(75)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.fd(25)
###############################################################
# Square = Town
# Circle = Fight
# Arrow = Quest Marker
# Turtle = Weapon Shops
# Triangle = Potion Shop
# Hollow Circle = Chest
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.stamp()
turtle.fd(50)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.fd(50)
turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.stamp()
turtle.back(50)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.fd(50)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.fd(50)
turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.stamp()
turtle.back(50)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.fd(50)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.fd(50)
turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.stamp()
turtle.fd(100)
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.stamp()
turtle.rt(90)
turtle.fd(140)
turtle.rt(90)
turtle.pd()
turtle.circle(10)
turtle.pu()
turtle.fd(150)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.back(10)



###############################################################    
turtle.st()
###############################################################

turtle.speed('fastest')

Map_Starting_Area()

turtle.color('orange')
turtle.shape('classic')

 print('You Continue with your Journey')
 print('You leave the protection of your farm and head into the open land')
print('You Come to a cross road')

while True:
    direction = input('Would you like to go North, South, East or West: ').lower()

if direction == 'north' and turtle.ycor() < GRID_UNIT * (GRID_SIZE//2 - 0.5):
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.update()
elif direction == 'south' and turtle.ycor() > -GRID_UNIT * (GRID_SIZE//2 - 0.5):
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.update()
elif direction == 'east' and turtle.xcor() < GRID_UNIT * (GRID_SIZE//2 - 0.5):
    turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() + GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.update()
elif direction == 'west' and turtle.xcor() > -GRID_UNIT * (GRID_SIZE//2 - 0.5):
    turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() - GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.update()
elif direction == 'quit':
    break
if turtle.pos == (0.00,50.00):
    combat()
```

Comment: Still does not work, some indentations incorrect.

Comment: Well Im not very good with the coding format on this site since it requires indetation and on the shell it doesn't

Comment: The most immediate problem is that I don't think the turtle will ever get close to (0, 50). When I run the code, and print the position, it is at an offset of (25, 25), and moves in steps of 50. However more importantly you can't really rely on floating point equality.

Comment: i know that the ofset is 25 and that each one is 50 apart and i teseted it in a seperate shell with the exact smae code and parameters and thats the exact coords i got from the turtle positioning functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a number of problems in your code which I've hopefully fixed:

```
#the imports are now all at the start - this is generally considered the way to go
import turtle
import random
import time

#constant declarations
GRID_UNIT = 50
GRID_SIZE = 5

HALF_GRID = GRID_SIZE // 2

SPIDER_LOCATIONS = [(1, 1),
                    (-1, 0)]

TREASURE_LOCATIONS = [(1, -2),
                      (-2, -1)]

TOWN_LOCATIONS = [(-2, -2),
                  (2, -2),
                  (-2, 2),
                  (2, 2)]

#simplified event functions
def combat():
    print("You stepped on a spider!")

def treasure():
    print("You found treasure!")

def town():
    print("You entered a town")

#scaled setpos for use with int grid coords
def grid_setpos(x, y, scale):
    turtle.setpos((x - 0.5) * scale, (y - 0.5) * scale)

#draw a grid
def draw_grid(size, unit):
    for x in range(-size // 2, size // 2 + 1):
        turtle.pu()
        turtle.setpos(x * unit, -size // 2 * unit)
        turtle.pd()
        turtle.setpos(x * unit, size // 2 * unit)

        turtle.pu()
        turtle.setpos(-size // 2 * unit, x * unit)
        turtle.pd()
        turtle.setpos(size // 2 * unit, x * unit)

#draw the map, iterating over stored global coordinates
def map_starting_area(size, unit):
    draw_grid(size, unit)

    # square = town
    # circle = fight
    # arrow = quest marker
    # turtle = weapon shops
    # triangle = potion shop
    # hollow circle = chest

    turtle.shape("circle")
    turtle.pu()

    for x, y in SPIDER_LOCATIONS:
        grid_setpos(x, y, unit)
        turtle.stamp()

    for x, y in TREASURE_LOCATIONS:
        turtle.pu()
        grid_setpos(x, y - 0.25, unit)
        turtle.pd()
        turtle.circle(unit // 4)

    turtle.shape("square")
    turtle.pu()

    for x, y in TOWN_LOCATIONS:
        grid_setpos(x, y, unit)
        turtle.stamp()

turtle.speed('fastest')

map_starting_area(GRID_SIZE, GRID_UNIT)

turtle.color('orange')
turtle.shape('classic')

print('you continue with your journey')
print('you leave the protection of your farm and head into the open land')
print('you come to a cross road')

turtle.showturtle()

turtle_x, turtle_y = 0, 0

grid_setpos(0, 0, GRID_UNIT)

while True:
    direction = input('would you like to go north, south, east or west: ').lower()

    if direction == 'north':
        if turtle_y < HALF_GRID:
            turtle_y += 1
        else:
            print("You hit a wall")

    elif direction == 'south':
        if turtle_y > -HALF_GRID:
            turtle_y -= 1
        else:
            print("You hit a wall")

    elif direction == 'east':
        if turtle_x < HALF_GRID:
            turtle_x += 1
        else:
            print("You hit a wall")

    elif direction == 'west':
        if turtle_x > -HALF_GRID:
            turtle_x -= 1
        else:
            print("You hit a wall")

    elif direction == 'quit':
        break

    grid_setpos(turtle_x, turtle_y, GRID_UNIT)

    if (turtle_x, turtle_y) in SPIDER_LOCATIONS:
        combat()

    if (turtle_x, turtle_y) in TOWN_LOCATIONS:
        town()

    if (turtle_x, turtle_y) in TREASURE_LOCATIONS:
        treasure()
```

The main point being addressed: How to "trigger" an event when a turtle hits a certain location. I've approached this by a number of changes to your code:

Firstly, as your turtle will always be on a grid, I'm tracking `turtle_x` and `turtle_y` separately from the turtle, as integers. This is important, as integers can be *properly* tested for equality. When the turtle is at a floating point location, it might not actually be possible to check if it is at a specific point. Each cell in the grid is one coordinate in the range `-HALF_GRID` to `HALF_GRID`, and the position is discretely changed by `1` or `-1`. Now you also need to know where each "event" is. I've done this by storing the locations of a number of events in global constant lists at the start of the file. By the way, I've also changed your map-drawing methods to use iteration over these lists, and for-loops for the grid drawing, as this was a lot clearer (it made the code easier to read and therefore debug for me, as well as being shorter). I hope you'll agree that `map_starting_area` is now easier to follow. As the coordinates being tracked are now integers, they need to be 'scaled up' whenever `setpos` is called. I've done this by writing a helper function `grid_setpos`, for setting position in a grid.

In short, it now stores a pair of *integers* to use as the turtles position, so it can test if anything is equal to then. It then does some maths with the turtle (scales each coordinate up by `GRID_UNIT`) to map the integer coordinates back onto the grid.

Previously, the turtle's coordinates were *floating point*. This means they were 'decimal' numbers (this is close enough to correct that it doesn't matter). However, as you were on a grid, you don't actually need a decimal number. Co-ordinates on a grid are *discrete* (whole numbers). Therefore, the co-ordinates are now being stored as whole numbers. This means it's possible to test if they're *exactly* equal. It also uses a list of coordinates of spiders, and uses some quick Python to see if the current coordinates are in this list: `if (turtle_x, turtle_y) in SPIDER_LOCATIONS:`.

I've simplified your methods for dealing with events (`combat()`, `town()`, `treasure()`) to a point where they demonstrate they're working, as that was all that was necessary for this question. You can expand on each of them to expand your game.

I've also changed your variable names. In Python, it's generally convention to use `underscore_case`, or maybe `camelCase` for variables and functions, but never `CapitalCase` (as this is for classes), and `Capital_Underscore_Case` is almost never used, to my knowledge.

Minor changes:

- Import statements are now all at the top
- Separated grid logic from map logic
- Some other bugs to do with when you were hiding/showing the turtle

If you want to generalise this more, and have different locations, different properties for events, etc I'd advise you to start writing some classes (with attributes such as `x`, `y`, and maybe instance methods like `encounter`. It's outside of the scope of this question (equality testing with turtle coordinates) to go into much, but there are many [tutorials](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Classes_and_Objects) on Python classes and their uses. I'd advise you to start simple and build up to integration with this project. If you get really stuck with your class implementation, you can of course always ask another question.

In response to your comment: it is generally not advised to create separate variables for eg each town. Lists are for when you have lots of a thing that needs to behave the same. Imagine if you had 50 towns, all in separate variables. If you want each town to keep track of a name/have different events, etc, refer to my section about classes. You'll need a list of Town instances, after acquainting yourself better with OO programming. If you get really confused about classes after trying to use them, post a specific question about your problem together with what you've got so far

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: My main concern is how the coords work and how i would change them since i want to have a variaty of maps each for a different location

Comment: Could you clairify how the coords work please? i understand how it works but i don't understand how it's mapped

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Would Their Be a specific way to edit the towns? the towns locations are TOWN_LOCATIONS = [(-2, -2),
                  (2, -2),
                  (-2, 2),
                  (2, 2)] and for each one i want to have a different map i could proberally use classes but im trying to avoid them

Comment: i understand that much about the coordinates but would their be a way to make a seperate varible for each of the coords

Answer (score 0):

`turtle.pos` is a function

```
import turtle 

print(turtle.pos)
turtle.pos == (0.00,50.00) # is always False

turtle.pos() == (0.00, 0.00) # might be what you want
```

Comment: Just replace the `turtle.pos` by `turtle.pos()` at the end. But there are other issues that you need to fix, see the elaborate answer above.